# How can i update two slice with same silde in nrrd loader

Tags: javascript, vtk

I am new to `Javascript` and `NRRD Loader`, in nrrd loader we can change the index value of a slice using the slider

```js
sliceY = volume.extractSlice('y', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[1]/2));
scene3.add(sliceY.mesh);

gui.add(sliceY, 'index', 0, volume.RASDimensions[1], 1).name('indexY').onChange(function () {
  sliceY.repaint.call(sliceY);
});
```

Consider I need update value of slicesX at same time with the same slider

```js
sliceX = volume.extractSlice('x', Math.floor(volume.RASDimensions[1]/2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used slider.js Javascript  which helped me to move the two slices using the same slider

```
$( function() { 
                  $( "#sliderx" ).slider({
                    min: 0,
                    max: volumeslicex,
                    step: 1,

                    stop: function( event, ui ) {
                        // planexy.material.color.setHex( 0x8d8d8d );
                        // preset = "NULL";
                    },

                    slide: function( event, ui ) {

                      indexX=ui.value;
                      scene1.remove( sliceX.mesh );
                      scene.remove( sliceX1.mesh );
                      sliceChange();

                    }
                  });
                } );
                    function sliceChange(){
                    //alert(indexX);
                    sliceX = volume.extractSlice('x',Math.floor(indexX));
                    sliceX1 = volume.extractSlice('x',Math.floor(indexX));
                    scene1.add( sliceX.mesh );
                    scene.add( sliceX1.mesh );
                    };
```

Comment: You just need to use slider.js that's it